# strange error when using source insight execute UV4

Tags: batch-file, arm, keil, source-insight

i want to execute UV4 in source insight, and catch the errors and display.
the batch file context is
    `c:\Keil\UV4\UV4.exe -b d:\workingcopy\test_project\test.uvproj  -o log`
    `type d:\workingcopy\test_project\log`
when i run the batch file, and the compile completed correct, it works fun.
but if the compile end by the error, the source insight will show ...\231 does not exist.

[image]

how to fix it ?

thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now i know where the devil is.
the error messages output by UV4, is PATH\FILE(LINE)
and the regex i use lead SI deal the line as a file.
the error line number is 231, so the SI show "231 does not exist"

Answer (score 0):

In my Python scripts which call uVision I check the error level of UV4 plus I parse the build log using regex. I always used this [manual](http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/uv4/uv4_commandline.htm) for reference.

Comment: well, i use that too. However, the devil is the regex and how SI deal with the output.